# Is it possible to open winform form from dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a visual studio windows forms application that has multiple projects, each having multiple forms. The project that loads on startup calls another project's form and closes its own. Referring to the startup program as "setup" and the other as "main". I have a scenario where I want to skip setup and be able to return to it later. Since setup is a dependency of main, and not the other way around, I cannot seem to create an instance of the setup form. Is this the case, or am I doing something wrong?

The call from setup to open main is as so

```
        this.Hide();
        frmDemo demo = new frmDemo();
        demo.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
```

I want to do the same thing from main to setup form, but I am having trouble.

Essentially it should just be

```
frmSetup setup = new frmSetup();
setup.show();
```

But this isn't working because it cannot find the form.

Comment: The startup Form is defined in Program.cs. You can define there the logic required to run any Form you need when the application is started. -- Your app starts before any Form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to reference Setup from Main then you need to add a reference in Main.

The problem then is that you will create a circular dependency, which is bad design (and I think you will also get compiler errors).

There are some ways to get around this, but the best approach it to make your Main program the first one that starts-up (not setup).  Then during startup it launches the set-up form and waits until it is finished and then continues.  And then when it needs to launch setup again, then it is no problem.

So you are effectively reversing the dependency.